# Passing id as a parametr of function

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="text" id="radioButtonWrapper" style="display:inline-block;">Gender</div>
  <div class="data">
    <div id="genderSection" style="display:inline-block;">
      <radiobutton [(model)]="gender" name="gender" value="Female" (modelChange)="reciveRadioButtonVal($event, IdasParameter )" required>Female</radiobutton>
      <radiobutton [(model)]="gender" name="gender" value="Male" (modelChange)="reciveRadioButtonVal($event, IdasParameter)" required>Male</radiobutton>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is possible pass to function some ID. In this example I would like pass id="radioButtonWrapper" in function `reciveRadioButtonVal($event, IdasParameter )`
where IdasParameter => "radioButtonWrapper"
I don't want using and passing this as a string  `reciveRadioButtonVal($event,radioButtonWrapper)`?

Comment: why can't you simply add a ref using `#radioButtonWrapper` attribute and pass it?

Comment: not model but ngModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a reference instead of id. That is `#radioButtonWrapper` and pass `radioButtonWrapper` to the function (not as a string. as a variable)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="text" #radioButtonWrapper style="display:inline-block;">Gender</div>
  <div class="data">
    <div id="genderSection" style="display:inline-block;">
      <radiobutton [(model)]="gender" name="gender" value="Female" (modelChange)="reciveRadioButtonVal($event, radioButtonWrapper )" required>Female</radiobutton>
      <radiobutton [(model)]="gender" name="gender" value="Male" (modelChange)="reciveRadioButtonVal($event, radioButtonWrapper)" required>Male</radiobutton>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can pass it with angular's element selector, setting a property on your radio button

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="text" id="radioButtonWrapper" #radioButtonWrapper style="display:inline-block;">Gender</div>
  <div class="data">
    <div id="genderSection" style="display:inline-block;">
      <radiobutton [(model)]="gender" name="gender" value="Female" (modelChange)="reciveRadioButtonVal($event,radioButtonWrapper)" required>Female</radiobutton>
      <radiobutton [(model)]="gender" name="gender" value="Male" (modelChange)="reciveRadioButtonVal($event,radioButtonWrapper)" required>Male</radiobutton>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It will be passed to your function as an angular element so in your function you should get it like this..

```
reciveRadioButtonVal(event, radiobutton){
    console.log(radiobutton.nativeElement);// this is the radio button
    console.log(radiobutton.nativeElement.id);// this is the id
}
```

Once you have the element you have access to all its properties..

Comment: when i use console.log(radiobutton) display <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="text" id="radioButtonWrapper" style="display:inline-block;">gender</div>. How to get id this element ?

Comment: console.log(radiobutton.nativeElement) return undefined